# Linux shell get device id from user input

Tags: linux, lsusb

So I am working on an install script for a program that needs the device id from lsusb in its configuration so I was thinking of doing the following:

```
$usblist=(lsusb)
#put the list into a array for each line.
#use the array to give the user a selection list usinging whiptail.
#from that line strip out the device id and vender id from the selected line.
```

The line looks as follows:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB to Serial
```

So I want only the 9 characters after "ID{space}"

Answer (score 0):

Just use, this uses `awk` to print out the `6th` field which in your case is the ID of the device

```
usblist="$(lsusb | awk '{print $6}')"
```

So you print any field you want, here are the mapping:

- $1 : Bus
- $2 : 001
- $3 : Device
- $4 : 004:
- $5 : ID
- $6 : 0665:5161
- $7 : Cypress
- $8 : Semiconductor
- $9 : USB
- $10 : to
- $11 : Serial

If you want to print more than one field , such as name , you can do like this

```
usblist="$(lsusb | awk '{print $7,$8,$9}')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first errors that I see are.
You wrote `$usblist=(lsusb | awk '{print $6}')`

You need to remove the `$` from the start, and add a `$` before the `(`. Some quotes will also help. i.e.

`usblist="$(lsusb | awk '{print $6}')"`

Answer (score 0):

Array assignment syntax in zsh, ksh93, bash, mksh or yash is:

```
array=( value1 value2... )
```

Getting the output of a command is `$(a command)`.

Splitting the output of a command on newline can be done with the `f` parameter expansion flag in `zsh` or in other shells by leaving that `$(...)` unquoted (the split+glob operator), after having assigned the newline character to the `$IFS` special variable and disabled globbing.

- `zsh`:

  ```
  array=( ${(f)"$(a command)"} )
  ```
- other shells (but also zsh)

  ```
  IFS='
  '
  set -o noglob # not needed in zsh unless in sh/ksh emulation
  array=( $(a command) )
  ```

To get the 6<sup>th</sup> blank delimited field of each of the lines of the output of a command, as others have said, you can use `awk '{print $6}'` or `grep -Po '^.*?ID \K.{9}'` (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible with perl-style regex support enabled) to get the nine characters after the first occurrence of `ID<space>` as you requested. So putting it altogether, that becomes:

```
array=( ${(f)"$(lsusb | awk '{print $6}')" ) # (zsh)
```

```
IFS='
'
set -o noglob
array=( $(lsusb | awk '{print $6}') )
```

Now, the default value of `$IFS` is space, tab, newline (and NUL in zsh), and USB ids in theory only contain hexadecimal digits and colons, so the output of `awk` should be guaranteed not to contain space, tab, nul nor glob characters, so if you can guarantee that `$IFS` still contains its default value, you can omit the first two commands and simplify it to:

```
array=( $(lsusb | awk '{print $6}') )
```

Or you could get the information directly from `/sys` without need for the `lsusb` nor `awk` command in `zsh` with:

```
array=(
  /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor(Ne['REPLY=$(<$REPLY):$(<$REPLY:h/idProduct)'])
)
```

Using globbing to find the `idVendor` files and the `e` glob qualifier to replace each glob expansion with the contents of that file and that of the `idProduct` file in the same directory (also has the benefit of giving you a sorted list).

Answer (score 0):

> usblist=`lsusb | awk '{print $6}'`
>
> echo $usblist

it should print 0665:5161, other than awk you can also use cut command.Check man page of cut for more info.

Comment: I get some duplicate values with this command - some of the Linux root hubs are the same. ```echo $(lsusb | awk '{print $6}' | sort -u)}``` seems OK though

Comment: Correction , it should be usblist=\`lsusb | awk '{print $6}'\`, if you are getting duplicate values then you can pipe above output to uniq

Comment: uniq doesn't do the job; echo $(lsusb | awk '{print $6}' | uniq ) gives [1d6b:0003 1d6b:0002 1d6b:0003 04b3:3003 04b3:3004 05e3:0610 0b05:1939 046d:c077 1d6b:0002] - that's  9 items - but echo $(lsusb | awk '{print $6}' | sort -u) gives [046d:c077 04b3:3003 04b3:3004 05e3:0610 0b05:1939 1d6b:0002 1d6b:0003] which is 7 items. Note man uniq - "Filter *adjacent* matching lines from INPUT (or standard input)..."